# Trying to listen for button click to be able to use as users selection js

Tags: javascript, html

Im writing a rock paper scissor lizard spock game i have the generateComputerChoice() function and decideWinner() function.

/**

- Generates a number between 1 and 5 and asigns it to a computer choice for the game
- @returns
  */

function generateComputerChoice() {

```
let comChoice = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);

if (comChoice === 1) {
    return "Rock";
} else if (comChoice === 2) {
    return "Paper";
} else if (comChoice === 3) {
    return "Scissors";
} else if (comChoice === 4) {
    return "Lizard";
} else if (comChoice === 5) {
    return "Spock";
} else {
    return "error";
}
```

}

/**

- Comapres the user choice from the buttons to the randomly generated computers choice
  */

function decideWinner() {

```
comChoice = generateComputerChoice();
userChoice = takePlayerChoice();

if (userChoice === comChoice) {
    console.log("game drew");
} else {
    if (userChoice === "Rock" && (comChoice == "Scissors" || comChoice == "Lizard")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Paper" && (comChoice == "Rock" || comChoice == "Spock")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Scissors" && (comChoice == "Paper" || comChoice == "Lizard")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Lizard" && (comChoice == "Spock" || comChoice == "Paper")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Spock" && (comChoice == "Scissors" || Comment == "Rock")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else {
        console.log("you lose")
    }
}
    console.log(userChoice);
    console.log(comChoice);
```

}
decideWinner()

But i need help getting the TakePlayerChoice() function to work it keeps returning undefined

/**Users choice is taken */

function takePlayerChoice() {

```
/* document.getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener("click", function() {*/
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (let button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.getAttribute("data-type") === "submit") {
                alert(" you clicked submit");
            } else {
                let userChoice = this.getAttribute("data-type");
               return "data-type";
            }
        })
    }
```

}

can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: This logic is wrong `userChoice === "Rock" && (comChoice == "Scissors" || comChoice == "Lizard")`. It should be `userChoice === "Rock" && comChoice == "Scissors"  ||  userChoice === "Rock" && comChoice == "Lizard")`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your function in deed should return undefined as you are not returning anything. The return statement is nested inside the callback on a button. The callback only happens when player presses the button and not when even is registered. To get the choice you have to change the gams state from within the callback. Another issue is that you are not returning actual choice but only a constant string.

So to recap, pass the button state directly to the function inside the button callback and also pass a correct state based of button.

Answer (score 0):

The decide winner function should be inside your button event listener because your function is already called before the user on some button. Or you put the user choice in a variable and then you trigger the decideWinner when the submit is clicked.
So remove the player choice function and add the content into window.onload to be sure that it is executed when the buttons are in the page:

```
window.onload = function() {
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
let userChoice = "";

for (let button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (this.getAttribute("data-type") === "submit") {
            alert(" you clicked submit");
            decideWinner(userChoice)
        } else {
            let userChoice = this.getAttribute("data-type");
           userChoice = "data-type";
        }
    })
}
}
```

And the decide winner should be like:

```
function decideWinner(userChoice) {
  comChoice = generateComputerChoice();
  if (userChoice === comChoice) {
    console.log("game drew");
  } else {
    if (userChoice === "Rock" && (comChoice == "Scissors" || comChoice == "Lizard")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Paper" && (comChoice == "Rock" || comChoice == "Spock")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Scissors" && (comChoice == "Paper" || comChoice == "Lizard")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Lizard" && (comChoice == "Spock" || comChoice == "Paper")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else if (userChoice === "Spock" && (comChoice == "Scissors" || Comment == "Rock")) {
        console.log("you win")
    } else {
        console.log("you lose")
    }
  }
  console.log(userChoice);
  console.log(comChoice);
}
```

and remove the decideWinner()